# Percentage calculation staying at first element in for loop

Tags: java, foreach, frequency

**EDIT**: Added code to show frequency count

This is not homework. I'm doing this for fun.

I hope this small snippet of code will suffice, but I've run into a strange issue. I counted the frequency of each number in an array, and that works fine. Well, I wanted to see the **percentage** of those frequencies, so I created a little method to calculate it.

Since the first element's frequency was 42, and my total characters were 1,553, it printed 2.7% for **every** element, rather than changing for the different frequencies.

I set up breakpoints during debugging, and once the frequency counter calculates the first element's frequency, that value sticks with the rest of the elements. O.o

I tried placing a for loop outside the percentage calculation, and it did the exact same thing. It never broke away from that first frequency counter.

```
   System.out.println(" FREQUENCY COUNT RESULT");
    Collections.sort(array);

    Hashtable<Integer, Integer> table = new Hashtable<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (table.containsKey(array.get(i))) {
            count = table.get(array.get(i));
            table.put(array.get(i), ++count);
        } else {
            table.put(array.get(i), 1);
        }
    }
    set = table.keySet();
    count = 0;
    for (Integer n : set) {
        count = table.get(n);
        System.out.println(n + ": Frequency - " + count);
    }
    System.out.println("TOTAL CHARACTERS IN ARRAY: " + countNonSpaces(array));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("PERCENTAGE REPORT");
    for(Integer n : set) {
        System.out.println(n + " Percentage: " + getPercentage(count, tally) + "%");
    }
}
public static double getPercentage(int count, int tally) {

    percentCounter = (count * 100.0) / tally;
    percentCounter = percentCounter * 100;
    percentCounter = Math.round(percentCounter);
    percentCounter = percentCounter / 100;
    return percentCounter;
}
public static int countNonSpaces(ArrayList<Integer> array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (array.get(i) != ' ') {
            tally++;
        }
    }
    return tally;
}
```

Everything is working except the percentage counter, so that's why I left the other code out.

This is a portion of the frequency output:

```
    10: Frequency - 54
    9: Frequency - 33
    8: Frequency - 37
    7: Frequency - 42
    6: Frequency - 35
    5: Frequency - 36
    4: Frequency - 40
    3: Frequency - 50
    2: Frequency - 39
    1: Frequency - 42 //<---IT'S STUCK HERE...????
    TOTAL CHARACTERS IN ARRAY: 1553
```

And this is the output of the same elements and their (**incorrect**) percentages:

```
    10 Percentage: 2.7%
    9 Percentage: 2.7%
    8 Percentage: 2.7%
    7 Percentage: 2.7%
    6 Percentage: 2.7%
    5 Percentage: 2.7%
    4 Percentage: 2.7%
    3 Percentage: 2.7%
    2 Percentage: 2.7%
    1 Percentage: 2.7%
```

Comment: Show us the code for printing the frequency!

Comment: @matt - Edited to show frequency

Comment: @csheridan I see you have also **edited** your `getPercentage` method to be as per my answer `getPercentage(int count, int tally)` - good work

Comment: The sum of all your frequencies (54+33+37+...) do not add up to 1553.  You have ten values that are all under 54; this cannot be over 540.  You compute the frequencies in a variable called  `array`, but you seem to be printing them from a variable called `set`.  Also, when you print "Percentage", the value of variable `count` is left to its last value when printing "Frequency".

Comment: @SciProg I only showed just a few of the values (there are actually 39 distinct numbers), and the tally isn't a **sum**, it's a character count. There are 1553 numbers in the array, not a sum of 1553. :-) If you look down below at my answer, I said "for the sake of brevity, I won't show every integer..." I only showed 10 of them, rather than wasting space with all 78 print statements.

Comment: It even says in my code "TOTAL CHARACTERS IN ARRAY"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Added code to show most frequent occurrences

Alright, I slept on it and tried again this morning. I set up breakpoints to see what was going on, and the counter was sticking at the first element, in which case was the integer 39, with a count of 42 occurrences. Every percentage was displaying as the percentage of 42 / 1558 (the tally of all characters excluding whitespaces). 
Since the percentage was essentially the same as the count, just divided by the tally, I got rid of the percentage method altogether, looped through the elements again, and made sure to **reset** the counter before entering the second loop. Here is the changed code (only including the count and tally methods. The other method is getFileInfo(), which just gets the numbers from a text file and puts them in an array):

```
public static void getCount(ArrayList<Integer> array) {

    Hashtable<Integer, Integer> table = new Hashtable<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (table.containsKey(array.get(i))) {
            count = table.get(array.get(i));
            table.put(array.get(i), ++count);
        } else {
            table.put(array.get(i), 1);
        }
    }
    set = table.keySet();
    count = 0;
    for (Integer n : set) {
        count = table.get(n);
        System.out.println(n + ": Frequency - " + count);
    }
    System.out.println();
    count = 0;
    System.out.println("PERCENTAGE REPORT");
    for(Integer n : set) {
        tally = 0; //<---Tally was being calculated twice. Had to reset.
        countNonSpaces(array); //get the tally once more after resetting
        count = table.get(n);
        double percentage = (count*100.0)/tally; //percentage is essentially "count" with an additional calculation so no new method needed
        percentage = percentage * 100;
        percentage = Math.round(percentage);
        percentage = percentage/100;
        System.out.println(n + ": Percentage - " + percentage + "%");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("MOST SIGNIFICANT PERCENTAGES");
    count = 0;
    for(Integer n : set) {
        tally = 0;
        countNonSpaces(array);
        count = table.get(n);
        percentage = (count*100.0)/tally;
        percentage = percentage * 100;
        percentage = Math.round(percentage);
        percentage = percentage/100;

        // Picked a decent number (50), copied the code
        // from the frequency calculation, and added
        // a continue statement to only print the most frequent #'s.

            if(count < 50) { 
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(n + ": Percentage - " + percentage + "%");
    }
}
public static int countNonSpaces(ArrayList<Integer> array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (array.get(i) != ' ') {
            tally++;
        }
    }
    return tally;
}
}
```

For the sake of brevity, I won't show every integer, but this is the new (**and correct**) output:

```
FREQUENCY COUNT RESULT
10: Frequency - 54
9: Frequency - 33
8: Frequency - 37
7: Frequency - 43
6: Frequency - 36
5: Frequency - 37
4: Frequency - 41
3: Frequency - 50
2: Frequency - 39
1: Frequency - 42

PERCENTAGE REPORT
10: Percentage - 3.47%
9: Percentage - 2.12%
8: Percentage - 2.37%
7: Percentage - 2.76%
6: Percentage - 2.31%
5: Percentage - 2.37%
4: Percentage - 2.63%
3: Percentage - 3.21%
2: Percentage - 2.5%
1: Percentage - 2.7%

TOTAL CHARACTERS IN ARRAY: 1558

MOST SIGNIFICANT PERCENTAGES
29: Percentage - 3.21%
15: Percentage - 3.59%
11: Percentage - 3.27%
10: Percentage - 3.47%
3: Percentage - 3.21%
```

Thanks for helping get my gears turning. It's much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are looping through a set, but not using any value from this set.

```
for(Integer n : set) {
    System.out.println(n + " Percentage: " + getPercentage(count) + "%");
}
```

It is hard to tell from your code, but if the set contains your Frequency and your count then you could calculate it

```
for(SomeObj n : set) {
    System.out.println(" Percentage: " + getPercentage(n.tally, n.count) + "%");
}
```

**Basically** you need both the tally and the count to calculate the percentage.  The tally and the count will be different for each row, and therefore need both to be stored in your set.

Answer (score 1):

the count variable you pass to getPercentage in your printing loop doesnt get updated at any stage during the loop.

You need to add getting count to your for loop for printing percentage, just as it is for the for loop for printing frequency

```
for(Integer n : set) {
        count = table.get(n);  // add this line in the loop for printing percentage
        System.out.println(n + " Percentage: " + getPercentage(count, tally) + "%");
    }
```

Comment: how would I go about updating it?

Comment: @csheridan: Updated anser